# Sytax error in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

What is wrong in the syntax of the below stored procedure in MySQL  ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
DECLARE @isbn varchar(17)
DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @price float(6,2)
DECLARE @totalbookpriceValue float(6,2)
DECLARE totalbookprice CURSOR
STATIC FOR 
(SELECT ISBN,COUNT(ISBN) FROM applieddb.cart c GROUP BY ISBN)
OPEN totalbookprice
IF @@CURSOR_ROWS > 0 BEGIN 
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_emp INTO @isbn,@count
 WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
SELECT ISBN,PRICE  FROM book INTO @price WHERE ISBN = @isbn 
PRINT 'Total Book Price is' + @price * @count
 FETCH NEXT FROM cur_emp INTO @isbn,@count
END
END
CLOSE totalbookprice
DEALLOCATE totalbookprice
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

ERROR Message:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@isbn varchar(17) DECLARE @count int DECLARE @price float(6,2) DECLARE @totalboo' at line 3
```

Changing the mysql query to the below also did not help and gave the following error: 
[image: Error on getting rid of the @]

Comment: The `SET NOCOUNT OFF` suggests that you are confusing SQL Server and MySQL syntax as does the use of `+` for string concatenation and the use of `@@` variables.  Try writing the stored procedure using MySQL syntax.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Do you have a reference for that?  The documentation says "For quoted strings, concatenation can be performed by placing the strings next to each other" and I always get `2` when I do `select '1' + '1'` and you can set a mode that allows `||` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pipes_as_concat).  But I've never seen `+` used for concatenation in MySQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I understand `||`.  Your statement was about `+`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: hmm, I'm pretty sure I saw `+` working for string concatenation, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Could you guide me on the above query after I changed it according to your comments ?

Answer (score 0):

`DECLARE` for local (without `@`) or `SET` for session (with `@`)

Answer (score 0):

```
***The solution to the above problem is as below:***
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `calculateTotalPrice`()
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT default 0;
DECLARE _isbn varchar(17);
DECLARE _count int;
DECLARE _price float(6,2);
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE _totalbookpriceValue float(6,2);
DECLARE totalbookprice CURSOR FOR  SELECT ISBN,COUNT(ISBN) FROM applieddb.cart c GROUP BY ISBN;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND set done= TRUE;
OPEN totalbookprice;

the_loop: LOOP
FETCH totalbookprice into _isbn,_count;
SET _price= (SELECT b.price from book b where b.ISBN = _isbn);
SET _totalbookpriceValue= _price*_count;  
SELECT _totalbookpriceValue;
IF done THEN
        CLOSE totalbookprice;
        LEAVE the_loop;
END IF;
-- count the number of times looped
SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;
END LOOP the_loop;
END
```